# Firebase not writing to expected child, updating it on next child in Android

Tags: android, json, firebase, android-recyclerview

Tried answers found on the internet, actually there is no change to the code as it seem correct but can't find where is the error.

My Input Parameters:

[image]

---

JSON RETURNED:
(I expected a "clocation" child and value but it won't even write that to the tree. Plus, the value of clocation is written to cbudget)

[image]

---

Project Class:

```
public class Project {

String ctitle, cdetail, clocation, cbudget;



public Project() {

}

public String getCtitle() {
    return ctitle;
}

public void setCtitle(String ctitle) {
    this.ctitle = ctitle;
}

public String getCdetail() {
    return cdetail;
}

public void setCdetail(String cdetail) {
    this.cdetail = cdetail;
}

public String getClocation() {
    return clocation;
}

public void setClocation(String clocation) {
    this.clocation = clocation;
}

public String getCbudget() {
    return cbudget;
}

public void setCbudget(String cbudget) {
    this.cbudget = cbudget;
}
```

---

MyViewHolder

```
public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {

    super(itemView);

    titleTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
    detailTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailTxt);
    locationTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.locationTxt);
    budgetTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.budgetTxt);


    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

---

MyAdapter

```
public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Project> projects) {
    this.c = c;
    this.projects = projects;
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model,parent,false);

    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final  Project s = projects.get(position);

    holder.titleTxt.setText(s.getCtitle());
    holder.detailTxt.setText(s.getCdetail());
    holder.locationTxt.setText(s.getClocation());
    holder.budgetTxt.setText(s.getCbudget());



    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int pos) {


            //OPEN DETAIL ACTIVITY
            openDetailActivity(s.getCtitle(),s.getCdetail(),s.getClocation(),s.getCbudget());
        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return projects.size();
}

//OPEN DETAIL ACTIVITY
private void openDetailActivity(String...details)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(c,DetailActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("TITLE_KEY",details[0]);
    i.putExtra("DETAIL_KEY",details[1]);
    i.putExtra("LOCATION_KEY",details[2]);
    i.putExtra("BUDGET_KEY",details[3]);

    c.startActivity(i);
}
```

---

FirebaseHelper

```
public class FirebaseHelper {

DatabaseReference db;
Boolean saved = null;
ArrayList<Project> projects=new ArrayList<>();

public FirebaseHelper(DatabaseReference db) {
    this.db = db;
}

//WRITE IF NOT NULL
public Boolean save(Project project)
{
    if(project==null)
    {
        saved=false;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            db.child("Project").push().setValue(project);
            saved=true;

        }catch (DatabaseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            saved=false;
        }
    }
    return saved;
}
//IMPLEMENT FETCH DATA AND FILL ARRAYLIST
private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
    projects.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {
        Project project = ds.getValue(Project.class);
       projects.add(project);
    }
}
//READ THEN RETURN ARRAYLIST
public ArrayList<Project> retrieve() {



    db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);

        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    return projects;
}

}
```

Receive and Bind Data:

```
    //RECEIVE DATA
    String title = i.getExtras().getString("TITLE_KEY");
    String detail = i.getExtras().getString("DETAIL_KEY");
    String location = i.getExtras().getString("LOCATION_KEY");
    String budget = i.getExtras().getString("BUDGET_KEY");

    //BIND DATA
    titleTxt.setText(title);
    detailTxt.setText(detail);
    locationTxt.setText(location);
    budgetTxt.setText(budget);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are declaring the `ArrayList<Project> projects=new ArrayList<>();` outside `onChildAdded()` and `onChildChanged()` methods. This means that your `projects` ArrayList is null, due the asyncronious behaviour of those methods, which are called before even you add those objects to the list.

To solve this, you need to declare that ArrayList inside `fetchData()` method right before that for loop.

This change will solve your problem.

Comment: Hello Alex, I moved `ArrayList<Project> projects=new ArrayList<>();` inside `fetchData()`, but the at the end of childEventListener i returned "return projects; " which is not identified now. what should i do?

Comment: You need also to move `db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {...` inside fetchData() method and remove the `retrieve()` entirely.

Comment: umm... as told moved childEventListener inside fetchData(). Main class was using retrieve method, and now its showing error. any solution? sorry for so much of a bother.

Comment: You need to change the logic of calling that method, because in that way you cannot use that ArrayList because it always be null.

Comment: I will tell you one thing if it helps, it was working with flying colors before I added the "clocation" child. When it only had Title, Description, and Budget. As soon as i add Location, it starts acting this weird. And since im a starter, i don't know other logics. thank you for all the effort. good day :)

Comment: Try to make a simple test. Comment all the other code which is not needed and use only this one and see if it works. Another approach will be to use [Firebase UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) which will handle all those methods for you.

Comment: hi again, did as you said. Tried adding Location to a clean backup copy i had when everything was working. Now, it works fluently. It worked with having `retrieve() method` and everything as it is. Didn't know where the problem was. Thank you so much, up-voted. You always save my day. Thanks again. cheers :)